# Why does menu bar show Siri using microphone?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, siri, microphone

Since updating to macOS 12.5 I always see an orange dot in the menu bar indicating that Siri is using the microphone.  It never goes away, even after I disabled Siri in System Preferences.  Is this a bug, or is there some way to tell if the microphone is *really* active?  I'm concerned about privacy and also battery life.  This is a 2019 MacBook Pro.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect this is just a bug, I've seen it on a couple of different Macs even pre-12.5. Haven't seen it since I updated to 12.5.1, but that was only an hour ago...

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to bring up the Siri (in my case by long hold of Command and Space). Then after the prompt disappeared also the microphone usage disappeared.